# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable with Python and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I need to process mysql data one row at a time and i have selected all rows put them in a tuple but i get the error above.

what does this mean and how do I go about it?

Answer (score 10):

1. Provide some code.
2. You probably call some function that should update database, but the function does not return any data (like `cursor.execute()`). And code:

   data = cursor.execute()

   Makes `data` a `None` object (of `NoneType`). But without code it's hard to point you to the exact cause of your error.

Answer (score 6):

It means that the object you are trying to iterate is actually None; maybe the query produced no results?
Could you please post a code sample?

Answer (score 5):

The function you used to select all rows returned None. This "probably" (because you did not provide code, I am only assuming) means that the SQL query did not return any values.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the cursor.rowcount variable after you call cursor.execute(). (this code will not work because I don't know what module you are using).

```
db = mysqlmodule.connect("a connection string")
curs = dbo.cursor()
curs.execute("select top 10 * from tablename where fieldA > 100")
for i in range(curs.rowcount):
  row = curs.fetchone()
  print row
```

Alternatively, you can do this (if you know you want ever result returned):

```
db = mysqlmodule.connect("a connection string")
curs = dbo.cursor()
curs.execute("select top 10 * from tablename where fieldA > 100")
results = curs.fetchall()
if results:
  for r in results:
    print r
```

Answer (score 2):

This error means that you are attempting to loop over a None object. This is like trying to loop over a Null array in C/C++. As Abgan, orsogufo, Dan mentioned, this is probably because the query did not return anything. I suggest that you check your query/databse connection.

A simple code fragment to reproduce this error is:

x = None

for each i in x:
    #Do Something
    pass

Answer (score 0):

This may occur when I try to let 'usrsor.fetchone' execute twice. Like this:

```
import sqlite3

db_filename = 'test.db'

with sqlite3.connect(db_filename) as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""
    insert into test_table (id, username, password)
    values ('user_id', 'myname', 'passwd')
    """)

    cursor.execute("""
    select username, password from test_table where id = 'user_id'
    """)

    if cursor.fetchone() is not None:
        username, password = cursor.fetchone()
        print username, password
```

I don't know much about the reason. But I modified it with try and except, like this:

```
import sqlite3

db_filename = 'test.db'

with sqlite3.connect(db_filename) as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""
    insert into test_table (id, username, password)
    values ('user_id', 'myname', 'passwd')
    """)

    cursor.execute("""
    select username, password from test_table where id = 'user_id'
    """)

    try:
        username, password = cursor.fetchone()
        print username, password
    except:
        pass
```

I guess the cursor.fetchone() can't execute twice, because the cursor will be None when execute it first time.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but I thought I'd add one more possibility.  I was getting this error when calling a stored procedure, and adding SET NOCOUNT ON at the top of the stored procedure solved it.  The issue is that earlier selects that are not the final select for the procedure make it look like you've got empty row sets.

Answer (score 0):

Try to append you query result to a list, and than you can access it. Something like this:

```
try:
    cursor = con.cursor()
    getDataQuery = 'SELECT * FROM everything'
    cursor.execute(getDataQuery)
    result = cursor.fetchall()  
except Exception as e:
    print "There was an error while getting the values: %s" % e
    raise


resultList = []

for r in result:
    resultList.append(r)
```

Now you have a list that is iterable.